# Upload single file on JSP page with one click

Tags: jsp, file-upload

I have a simple form that uploads a selected file using Apache Commons Upload 1.2.2. The form has only one field to specify one file name, and 2 buttons, Browse and Submit, like so:

```
<form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I'd like to be able to make this a one click operation (as soon as the file is selected, it is submitted), rather than 2 button clicks (file select then submit). Any suggestions would be appreciated, TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let JavaScript submit the parent form on change of the input field.

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="filename" onchange="submit()" />
</form>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, based on your question history you seem to be already using Servlet 3.0. I'd suggest to just use the new API provided `request.getPart()` method instead of Apache Commons FileUpload. See also [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some Javascript or Flash component to achieve this.

E.g. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/